# 4 bit Binary Addition in C++

Tags: c++, binary

We were given an assignment to make a program that takes two decimal numbers as input and performs binary addition in the background then outputs a decimal sum.  I seem to be getting the wrong results despite how much I think my code logic is correct.

My current sum gives me 0. The Correct answer should be 24.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int add(int, int);
int decbin(int);
int bindec(long);
int binADD(string, string);

int main()
{
    int a = 15;
    int b = 9;
    int z;
    z = add(a,b);
    cout << z;
    return 0;
}


int add(int a, int b)
{
    int z;
    ostringstream x, y;
    x << decbin(a);
    y << decbin(b);
    z = binADD(x.str(), y.str());
    return z;
}

int decbin(int x)
{
    int d[16];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int ans;


    while(x > 0)
    {
        d[i] = x % 2;
        i++;
        x = x / 2;
    }

    for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
       ans = d[j];

    }

     return ans;
}

int bindec(int x)
{
    int bin, dec = 0, rem, base = 1;

    bin = x;
    while (x > 0)
    {
       rem = x % 10;
       dec = dec + rem * base;
       base = base * 2;
       x = x / 10;
    }

    return dec;
}

int binADD(string a, string b)
{
   int carry = 0;
   int result[5];
   int res;
   int ans;


  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {

    if(a[i] == '1' && b[i] == '1' && carry == 0)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
        carry = 1;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '0' && b[i] == '1' && carry == 1)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
        carry = 1;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '1' && b[i] == '1' && carry == 1)
    {
        result[i] = 1;
        carry = 1;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '1' && b[i] == '0' && carry == 1)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
        carry = 1;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '1' && b[i] == '0' && carry == 0)
    {
        result[i] = 1;
        carry = 0;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '0' && b[i] == '0' && carry == 1)
    {
        result[i] = 1;
        carry = 0;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '0' && b[i] == '1' && carry == 0)
    {
        result[i] = 1;
        carry = 0;
    }
    else if(a[i] == '0' && b[i] == '0' && carry == 0)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
        carry = 0;
    }

}

result[4] = carry;
for(int j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
{
   res = result[j];
}

ans = bindec(res);
return ans;

}
```

Comment: Please spell out your "wrong results", and what you expected instead.

Comment: How are your results wrong? What are your results? What should they be?

Comment: `decbin` isn't returning what you think it is.

Comment: @ Scott Hmm your right, I tried printing out decbin in my add() function and seems to give me the wrong results. However if I print it out in my decbin() function it gives the correct values 15 = 1111, and 9 = 1001

Comment: You are not accumulating your ans in decbin, only assigning to a different power of 2 each time. Your digits will be correct within the d array within the function but the returned ans will be wrong (unless your input  x is a power of 2)

Comment: At the bottom of your add function print each element of the array to check if they are correct.  It looks like a bug in turning the correct array into the final output

Comment: Just so it's said:  Once you start worrying about binary vs decimal digits, the result *is no longer a number.*  It's a sequence of digits, and by rights ought to be a string.

Comment: My main problem is that my decbin,binADD, and bindec functions all return values "by index." Is there anyway I can store them in one string?

Comment: Obviously it's possible to have one string containing all the binary digits of a number -- `binADD` is already taking two such strings.  :)  But you might be better off with a `bitset`, which is actually made for stuff like this.  Depends on whether binary<->decimal conversion is part of what you're trying to pick up.

Comment: @cHao yes I did consider using those, but we're not allowed to use them. As to using strings, how do I pass the result of decbin to a string x?

Comment: Something like `string bits; while (n > 0) { bits += (n & 1) + '0'; n >>= 1; }` would give you the bits little-endian style.  From there, `string(digits.rbegin(), digits.rend())` would give you the big-endian form you're used to.  (But frankly, math is simpler with little-endian.  I'd keep it that way til the math is done and you have to convert/display the result.)

Comment: err, s/`digits`/`bits`/g :P